# LBR for large programs

Tags: intel, compiler-optimization, perf, msr, pgo

The Last Branch Record feature in Intel processors. Are they suitable for large programs that have a lot of branching? If yes how do you manage to find the entire path by just using 16 MSR registers incase of Haswell?

Answer (score 0):

The LBR feature can trace the source and destination of only (up to 32 depending on the processor model, not 16 as you said) most recent control transfer instructions. Fore more information, refer to section 17.4.8 of the Intel software developer manual volume 3.

However, if you want to trace a large number of control transfer instructions, you can use another feature called Branch Trace Store (BTS). Fore more information, refer to sections 17.4.5, 17.4.6 and 17.4.9 of the Intel software developer manual volume 3.